# Firefox 59 and self signed certificates error on local environnement

Tags: apache, ssl, firefox, ssl-certificate

On my local environment (https://app.dev) based on Windows -> Docker -> Apache 2.4, the new version of Firefox (59) blocks the self signed certificate. (It works fine until this version)

The message returned is:

```
app.dev uses an invalid security certificate.
The certificate is not trusted because it is self-signed.
Error code: SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER
```

and I can't add an Exception.

If you have the same problem, your help will be welcome.

Comment: Firefox probably followed Google Chrome in having HSTS preloaded on \*.dev domains. Don't use public domains internally.

Comment: it works. I replace .dev with .localhost